# linq xml extract text between tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm using Linq query to extract data from Xml file. I'm trying to extract data from tags and extra data, i.e. text, preserving the order. 
In other words giving the following xml excerpt:

```
<item>
 <elementA id="1" value="aaaa">zazaz
 <elementB id="2" value="bbbb">wwwww
 <elementC id="3" value="cccc">sssss
</item>
```

And I'm using the following statements to extract:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(@"
   <item>
         <elementA id="1" value="aaaa"/>zazaz
         <elementB id="2" value="bbbb"/>wwwww
         <elementC id="3" value="cccc"/>sssss
   </item>");
var nav = root.Descendants();
StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();
foreach (var x in nav)
{
  content.Append(x.Name.LocalName)
       .Append(": id=")
       .Append(x.Attribute("id").Value)
       .Append(": value=")
       .Append(x.Attribute("value").Value)
       .Append(" extra data= ")
       .Append(x.Value)
       .Append("\n");
 }
 Console.WriteLine(content.ToString());
```

and it extracts:

```
elementA: id=1: value=aaaa extra data: 
elementB: id=2: value=bbbb extra data: 
elementC: id=3: value=cccc extra data:
```

instead of:

```
elementA: id=1: value=aaaa extra data: zazaz
elementB: id=2: value=bbbb extra data: wwwww
elementC: id=3: value=cccc extra data: sssss
```

So, with ".Value" the text between tags is not extracted.
Are there any tricks to perform it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Nodes()` and check `NodeType`.

```
foreach (XNode node in root.Nodes())
{
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        XElement elem = (XElement)node;

        content.Append(elem.Name.LocalName)
            .Append(": id=")
            .Append(elem.Attribute("id").Value)
            .Append(": value=")
            .Append(elem.Attribute("value").Value);
    }
    else if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        XText text = (XText)node;

        content.Append(" extra data= ")
            .Append(text.Value.Trim())
            .AppendLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your XML appears to be malformed. XML is a strict format that requires closing tags.

```
<item>
 <elementA id="1" value="aaaa">zazaz</elementA>
 <elementB id="2" value="bbbb">wwwww</elementB>
 <elementC id="3" value="cccc">sssss</elementC>
</item>
```

Close your tags, and the code will likely work.

Per the MSDN documentation for the [XElement.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property, Value returns "A String that contains all of the text content of this element. If there are multiple text nodes, they will be concatenated."

Given this, think you're on the right track, and that the issue is likely your data format.

**UPDATE**

I modified your XML as shown above, and ran your code through LINQPad 4. The following was returned:

```
elementA: id=1: value=aaaa extra data= zazaz
elementB: id=2: value=bbbb extra data= wwwww
elementC: id=3: value=cccc extra data= sssss
```

It does, indeed, appear to be an issue with the data format.

Comment: I think he messed up his sample XML. XLinq won't even parse that.

Comment: The problem is that my XML is a text document parsed and annotated using XML tags. I have to extract both annotated element and free text.

Comment: The sample is actually valid (though ugly) XML. The element* tags, are properly closed (with no text nodes in themselves), and the 'zazaz', etc parts are text nodes of 'item' (actually siblings of the associated elements).